# ggplot unable to fill plot by dataframe variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to plot a dataset and have the points filled dependent on a variable within the dataset; however, I am not getting the results I expected with the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.5
library(RColorBrewer)
#> Warning: package 'RColorBrewer' was built under R version 4.0.3
df <- data.frame(
         ID   = c("B2008","0E00A", "24101"),
         Rate = c(0.12016, 0.12528, 0.24614),
         Pos  = c(0.0796, 0.0849, 0.18316),
         Neg  = c(0.0249, 0.0249, 0.0925),
         Ret  = c(0.0547, 0.06, 0.09066),
         EmpCategory = c("Full-Time", "Part-Time", "Un-Employed")
      )


head(df, 2)
#>      ID    Rate    Pos    Neg    Ret EmpCategory
#> 1 B2008 0.12016 0.0796 0.0249 0.0547   Full-Time
#> 2 0E00A 0.12528 0.0849 0.0249 0.0600   Part-Time

## Plot Rate vs Return, filled by Employee Category, sized by Negative (Losses)
ggplot(df) +
    aes(x=Rate,y=Ret,fill=EmpCategory,size=Neg) +
    geom_point() +
    xlab("Rate") +
    ylab("Return") +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette='RdYlGn')


## Plot Rate vs Return, filled by Positive (gains), sized by Employee Category
ggplot(df) +
    aes(x=Rate,y=Ret,fill=Pos,size=EmpCategory) +
    geom_point() +
    xlab("Rate") +
    ylab("Return") +
    scale_fill_distiller(palette='RdYlGn')
#> Warning: Using size for a discrete variable is not advised.
```

[First ggplot call produces this plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkYiY.png)
[Second ggplot call produces this plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z20VR.png)

As you can see, regardless of whether I use a categorical or continuous variable, it doesn't seem that I can fill the color of the points by variable.  Any and all insight into what I am doing incorrectly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `color = EmpCategory` instead of `fill`.

More about color related aes here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_colour_fill_alpha.html